# Unable to invoke max with an argument list of type String

Tags: swift, realm

I'm starting to try realm with swift and have some basic difficulties.

This is my model:

```
class Alarm: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var name: String!
    dynamic var date: NSDate!

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Now I want to calculate the `nextId` for saving a record. I write something like this:

```
let nextId = realm.objects(Alarm).max("id")
```

But XCode throws me an error:

> Cannot invoke 'max' with an argument list of type '(String)'.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is function declaration in RealmSwift: public func max<U: MinMaxType>(property: String) -> U? . It indeed requires a string parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let nextId = realm.objects(Alarm).max("id") as Int?
```

You need to tell Swift what the return type of `max()` should be at the call site because it varies depending on the type of the property that you name in the string parameter. It needs to be `Int?` rather than just `Int` because there is no maximum if there are no objects.

Comment: thank for well-explained answer. Swift sometimes is not so obvious

Comment: How would I do this with `Int64`? I'm getting the error _Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' to 'Swift.Int64'_ when I use `Int64`

Comment: I use Realm 2.4.1 and I have the follow line: `let sum: Int? = self.currentDay?.periods.sum(ofProperty: "steps") as? Int`

And I get this error, is there someone who can tell me the error: Generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred

Periods is a Realm List